# SonarQube Directory Exclusions vNext Component Issue

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I've been having some difficulty with exclusions in SonarQube. I haven't really seen this particular situation posted here, and following some other solutions suggested in exclusion-related questions has not solved the issue. Any insight would be really appreciated.

I've been working with an engineer on filtering the files SonarQube is analyzing from their project during build time. Their solution is being built via a vNext build, where TFS and the build server are hosted on-prem. SonarQube is also hosted on-prem. The build is using the Sonar components included with vNext for the analysis. The project is primarily C#.

The solution consists of mostly projects exclusive to that solution, but there a few projects references that are part of another app entirely. Because of this, the workspace mapping has to get files from 2 separate parts of source control. Also, because of the way the solution is looking for the projects (based on the properties of the solution file itself), I have to map the source control files in a specific way. At a high level, the workspace on the build server looks something like this:

[image]

In the sonar settings file, the working directory is set to the Build Source Folder

The engineer wants to exclude code files from specific directories from analysis. For example, they want to exclude all cs files from folder X within B.Srvc. So, the directory would be Build Source Directory/B/Source/B.Srvc/X. Based on the exclusion instructions found on SonarQube's website, it sounded like I just needed to do something like this:

```
sonar.exclusions=Build Source Directory/B/Source/B.Srvc/X/**/*.cs
```

When I did that, it still analyzed the files within that folder. I tried various other combinations of patterns like:

```
sonar.exclusions=Build Source Directory/B/Source/B.Srvc/X/*.cs
sonar.exclusions=**/X/**/*.cs
sonar.exclusions=B/Source/B.Srvc/X/**/*.cs
sonar.exclusions=**/B/Source/B.Srvc/X/**/*.cs
```

I've even tried giving the complete directory path (so, C:/agent/_work/25/src/...) but that did not work either.

Very broad exclusions like **/* Name *.cs work perfectly fine, but if I want to start excluding files from certain directories, I can't get anything to work.

I feel like I'm missing something really basic, but I just can't figure it out. I've been trying to solve this issue for awhile when I have time, but I haven't made any progress. If anyone could provide any insight, I would really appreciate it. If you need any additional information, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SonarQube interface, look at one of the files you want to exclude. At the top, you will see the file path as SonarQube understands it. It is this path that you want to use when you enter your exclusions **through the UI** not the analysis settings.

Because of the structure of exclusion properties, they are very, very difficult to set up correctly in analysis properties. That's *why* doing so is not documented.

Instead, you should **enter exclusions through the UI**.

Comment: This worked! I knew it was going to be something basic. Thank you so much! That sort of brings up another question, but it might warrant an entirely different topic. How exactly does Sonar determine the file path? The reason I ask is because the path it is showing within the UI doesn't quite match what is on the server. It seems like it might be constantly changing the working directory when doing analysis and determining the file path from that location? Sorry if this is a dumb question. I sort of inherited this tool, so I'm trying to learn more about it.

Comment: That's definitely a separate question :-)